# Write a program to sum all the integers between 1 and 1000, that are divisible by 13, 15 or 17, but not by 30

Tags: java, while-loop, conditional-statements

This my code i don't know what to do next I'm totally beginner

```
        int number = lb;
        while(number <= ub){
            if (number % 7 == 0 && number % 15 == 0 && number % 17 == 0 && number % 30 != 0 ){
                sum+= number;       

            }
            number++;               
        }
        System.out.println("Answer: " + sum);
    }

}
```

Comment: divisible by 13, 15, OR 17 means you should have used an OR and not an AND

Comment: hint --> `||` is not `&&`.

Comment: You need this kind of `if` .`if ((number % 13 == 0 || number % 15 == 0 || number % 17 == 0) &&number % 30 != 0 ){}`

Comment: ...and a for loop is likely going to be more clear to you instead of a while loop.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do something like this

```
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){ // iterate from 0 to 1000
        if ((i % 13 == 0 || i % 15 == 0 || i % 17 == 0) &&i % 30 != 0 ){
           // take numbers divide by 13 or 15 or 17 which not divide by 30
           sum=sum+i; // adding that number to current sum
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Answer: " + sum); // final sum
```

Out put:

```
    Answer: 76795
```

Answer (score 3):

do it in one line using the latest release, Java 8:

```
package com.example;

import static java.util.stream.IntStream.rangeClosed;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        out.println(rangeClosed(1, 1000)
                   .filter(n -> n % 13 == 0 || n % 15 == 0 || n % 17 == 0)
                   .filter(n -> n % 30 != 0)
                   .sum());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, it should be as simple as

```
int sum = 0;
// from 1 to 1000
for (int num = 1; num <= 1000; num++) {
  if (num % 30 == 0) {
    continue; // If it's divisible by 30, skip it.
  }
  if (num % 13 == 0 || num % 15 == 0 || num % 17 == 0) {
    sum += num; // If it's divisible by 13 or 15 or 17 add it to sum.
  }
}
System.out.printf("sum = %d%n", sum);
```

Output is

```
sum = 76795
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int number = 0b1; //the proper way to start a binary number
            int sum = 0;
while(number <= 1000){
 if ((number % 13 == 0 || number % 15 == 0 || number % 17 == 0) && number % 30 != 0 ) {
  sum+= number;

   }
 number++;
}
 System.out.println("Answer: " + sum);
```

In the question you said numbers that are divisible by 13 or 15 or 17 and not by 30, so apply that same logic to the if statement. That would give you the right result.

**Answer: 76795**

Comment: `number % 7 == 0` for what ?