# My C program gives me a different output from the code I saw here written in Java. (purpose is the same)

Tags: c

Task is to "Write a program to sum all the integers between 1 and 1000, that are divisible by 13, 15 or 17, but not by 30". Here is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int number = 1;
   int sum = 0;

   while(number <= 1000) {
       ++number;

       if(((number % 13 ==0) || (number % 15 ==0) || (number % 17 ==0)) && (number % 30 != 0)){
           sum = sum + number;
       }
   }
    printf("Sum equals to %d.\n", sum);
    return (0);
}
```

Output in my case is "Sum equals to 77796."
While on [one of the posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25112633/5567382) it has "sum = 76795".

I don't understand why is that, tried changing code in different ways, but couldn't get to that answer.

Comment: You should probably put your `++number` after your calculations, not before them, since the difference is 1000 + 1.

Comment: The other program iterates from 0 to 999 -- yours, 1 to 1000.

Comment: @Crowman Not **probably** but **definitely** (as in the *working* answers to the linked question). You should post an answer.

Comment: You do know that C has `for` loops, right?

Comment: There were 3 comments saying that 76795 was correct and since I just started learning yesterday, I thought someone way more experienced in this field would have correct solution to this problem.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your suggestions! Will try them out and post an updated code in comments. @FiddlingBits I used for loop first but compiler was giving me weird error and once I replaced it with while loop, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For an idea of the problem, start by looking at the difference in results. You get 77796, while you expect 76795. The difference between these is 1001, which is a very big hint.

The line `++number;` adds one to `number`, and you have this line before the code that does the check. By doing this you remove 1 from your search domain, and add the value 1001 to it.

To fix this, you can move the increment below the main body of the loop, as it was in the original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number = 1;
    int sum = 0;

    while (number <= 1000) {
        if(((number % 13 == 0) || (number % 15 == 0) || (number % 17 == 0)) && (number % 30 != 0)){
            sum = sum + number;
        }

        ++number;
    }

    printf("Sum equals to %d.\n", sum);
    return (0);
}
```

This could be better written using a `for` loop, which exist for this purpose:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;

    for(int number = 1; number <= 1000; ++number) {
        if(((number % 13 == 0) || (number % 15 == 0) || (number % 17 == 0)) && (number % 30 != 0)){
            sum = sum + number;
        }
    }

    printf("Sum equals to %d.\n", sum);
    return (0);
}
```

Both of these output the desired result:

```
Sum equals to 76795.
```

Comment: Does this produce OP's expected result, 76795?

Comment: @FiddlingBits Yes, it does

Comment: You should include that in your answer.  I would have guessed not because the program in OP's link iterates from 0 to 999.  Maybe I misread the program.

Comment: Yes, it does! May I ask which is the preferred way to use loop functions, using for or while?

Comment: @FiddlingBits The original unedited question linked to the question in general, as opposed to the specific answer. The original code in that question uses a `<=`. The answer that Weather Vane edited this question to point to is the only to use `<`, and seems to be the wrong one to point to, given that OP included "sum = 76795".

Comment: Since `1000` is not divisible by `13`, `15`, `17` or `30` it won't matter.

Comment: @Solune It's a decision you need to make depending on what you need to do. If it makes sense to have an index, it's usually a `for` loop that you want to use. Both of those loops can replace each other, you have to choose the one that gives the cleanest and most readable code.

Comment: ...but it's unclear which is the one to link to, since they are all using different combinations of factors,  `&&`, `||` and parenthesis.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think the problem itself wasn't written clearly. " by 13, 15 or 17, but not by 30" can be understood in different ways, but in my opinion it's 13 or 15 or 17, that's why I used code written with OR operators as a reference. All the answers there had || operators between these three numbers and && when it came to 30, I think writing style is different and that's it, some of them combines all conditions together, some divided it in a way that the case for "30" was itself separate if function. I guess it's style preference.